# Anonymous array assignment in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Firefox (v 16) has no problem with this anonymous array assignment from a function:

```
var x = 0; var y = 0;
[x,y] = incr1(x,y);  // x,y now both equal 1
function incr1(x,y) {
    return [x+1,y+1];
}
```

using the developer tools in Chrome (v 18) on the other, it hand complains "Uncaught reference error: invalid left hand side in assignment"

Comment: Can you link to a source that makes you think that syntax is valid JavaScript?

Comment: @maerics The fact that it somehow "works" in FF is compelling enough for me...I'm not sure exactly what's happening, but

Comment: That's called destructuring assignment. It's one of the additions to Mozilla's JS implementation, and is likely coming in ES6.

Comment: @maerics, Ian - This is a [JS v1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7) feature that (so far) only works in FF.

Comment: @Ian: sure, just wondering how you discovered that it works in FF!

Comment: This is useful for other stuff, like variable swaps. `[a, b] = [b, a]`. No more `temp` variables!

Comment: @maerics I'm not the OP! Haha but it seems that the OP tried it because it's possible in perl, and it ended up "working"

Comment: @Ian: ah yes, that makes sense.  I think I've even done that in Ruby for swapping items, per squint's comment.

Comment: It's a little weird though that the syntax subverts the way arrays usually work; `[x,y]` usually contain copies of `x` and `y` if they're primitive types, but here they seem to contain references. Potentially confusing.

Comment: @bfavaretto, Yes, x and y in this context are references, in the same way as the left hand side of a simple assignment is required to be a reference:  x = expression.

Comment: @bfavaretto: They're not references. They're just copies of the return value of the function. It can be used with any complex data structure, like: `var o = {foo: [1,2,3], bar: "string"}; var {foo: [a,b,c], bar:d} = o;` The variables `a,b,c,d` will get a copy of the values held in `o`.

Comment: I can't really think of good reason to use that syntax.  I am curious what you are using it for.

Comment: @squint So when on the left-hand side `[x,y]` is not an actual array, it's like a template for the data structure on the other side? And later it evaluates to an actual array (`a` in `var a = [x,y] = incr1(x,y)`)? Interesting, but I'm still confused. Okay, I guess I'll have to read the ES6 draft section on that...

Comment: @bfavaretto: Yeah, the LHS isn't an Array. It's just a structure that is expected *(to a certain degree)* to match the structure on the RHS. To the degree that the structures match, the values on the RHS will be assigned to the variables on the LHS. This *(or something similar to it)* is referred to as "pattern matching" in some other languages. Erlang makes heavy use of this sort of assignment. I think Rust also has something similar.

Comment: @Brad: Are you referring to the OP, or to my example?

Comment: @squint, The original question from tgoneil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox is the only browser that supports that syntax.

Comment: Is this ES6? Do you know what to search for to find this? Or already know of anything specific to learn about it?

Comment: Ok, so is there a way in javascript to assign to anonymous array without having to declare a var and then having to de-reference it?

Comment: @tgoneil The above code does not assign to an anonymous array. It's some custom syntax for taking an array and splitting the elements into separate variables. It's not like there's an array `[x, y]` that is being assigned a new value. After all, if it really were an array, then you could write `[1, 2] = incr1(x,y)` and then um what happens?

Comment: Ian, I just tried using that syntax, since other languages like perl support anonymous array assignment.  Saves unnecessary code.

Comment: @tgoneil I understand, I'm just wondering if there's somewhere that explains what this is, since Kolink knows only FF supports this. Like some documentation

Comment: Raymond, well of course you wouldn't use this to overwrite a constant, but as I mentioned, anonymous array assignment is valid in other languages.

Comment: @bfavaretto Cool, thanks. Before this discussion, I wouldn't have known what to call it. I'm not sure if I should feel ashamed for not knowing that programming term...

Comment: @bfavaretto Wait, that link doesn't work! Ahh I see, the referring page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_(Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection)) has planned to move it to its own page, at that address

Comment: Sorry, I copied a red link from MDN. Working link is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_(Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection). And I also didn't know about that feature or its name, either in JavaScript 1.7, or in ES6. All I knew was PHP's similar feature (expand/compact), and, coincidentally, yesterday I was thinking if that could exist in js too.

Comment: Thanks for updating that link, and thanks all for helping me with this.